# for 12V 4 leds are not glowing

Tags: 12v

[image]

FOR 12v 4 LEDS ARE NOT GLOWING. LAST ONE IS GOING PROBLEM. AFTER USING VOLTAGE DIVIDING NETWORK ALSO leds droping voltage  is 6V,3V,3V,1V simultennisly. so last one not glowing. please tell me the cause

Comment: The circuit is wrong. Make a bit of analysis.. and fix your question as well.

Comment: Ask yourself what kind of LED's are these? What is the voltage drop? What is the total voltage drop across all LED's in the first circuit?

Comment: It would be nice if you could ask a question, tell us why you think it won't work, what you've done to try and get it to work and why. Include equations based on electrical principals.

Comment: Guys, I think we're still at the crayon stage. Answer below.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT. And proper grammar would make your question much clearer.

Comment: You've told us nothing about the LEDs themselves or where or how you measured those voltages. This 'question' is barely any more answerable than your previous attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feiuYR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1 and 2. Series option uses 10 mA total. Parallel option uses 10 mA per leg.*

Comment: Thank you for accepting this answer. There is a schematic editor on the toolbar so you don't have to use _Paint_ to draw schematics!